# how to crop image in photoshop save and not loose original psd after saving

Tags: image, crop, photoshop, psd

basically after i crop an image in Photoshop from a PSD and save it, the original psd is lost.  How can i not loose the original PSD after cropping and saving? Here are the steps in more detail:

```
1) i open a psd in Photoshop
2) I click the cropping tool in left hand side
3) i select the area i want to crop
4) I save the cropped area as a separate png file
```

now after step 4, i loose the original psd the cropped image was from, but how can i not loose the original psd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually programming with `ExtendScript`, use a snapshot before you do your stuff, then revert afterwards like this:

```
// get docRef
var docRef = app.activeDocument;

// take a snapshot to revert to
var savedState = docRef.activeHistoryState;

// ... do your stuff

// revert to initial state
docRef.activeHistoryState = savedState;
```

If you are not actually programming but just mousing around in Photoshop graphically, go to the `Window` menu across the top of Photoshop and turn on the `History` window. Then click on the `Open` button to go back to how the document looked when you opened it before you did your cropping.